# JQuery Gallerriffic plugin works locally but not remotely?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the wicked [Gallerriffic plugin](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/) on a gallery page, and got it working locally... but for some frustrating reason it doesnt work when i upload the files to the server (in any broswer)!

http://www.brookhouserh.co.uk/photo-gallery.html

Thats the link to the gallery... it is picking up some of the jquery because the opacity stuff works! just not the slideshow stuff....

Totally baffled as to what could be going wrong... any suggestions/help really really appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the images are missing. The gallery is working, but because the image isn't on the server it will never "load".

Here are some examples of missing images...

http://www.brookhouserh.co.uk/css/images/brook_house_care_home.gif

http://www.brookhouserh.co.uk/images/005.jpg

http://www.brookhouserh.co.uk/images/006.jpg

Maybe you have put them in a different location or have forgotten to actually upload them?

Comment: oh yeh! sorry! schoolgirl error! thanks for spotting that one!